# JSF parameter passing

Tags: parameters, error-handling, jsf-2, facelets

I'm using JSF 2.0 with Facelets and I want to do something like this:
I have a web application with specific custom Exceptions. I would like to have a general error page, which can display the error messages of the exceptions. So for example if a custom exception occurs in a managed bean, i'd like to navigate to exception.xhtml, and pass a string paramater, and then display it somehow.
Is there any easy way to do this?

thanks,
M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Action bean you should have something like:

```
public String handleException(){
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put("myException", exceptionObj);
    return "exceptionPage";
}
```

(in this action method you can do whatever you need, and when you get the required exception you put it in the request as so and navigate to your page i.e. exceptionPage.jsf)

And in the target page's (exceptionPage.jsf) Action you can retrieve it by:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("myException");
```

and connect it to a component in exceptionPage.jsf by a getter.